# 'require' in a subdirective depending on parent directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to construct a sub directive which will later be used in multiple directives.

These parent directives have the same controller that provides some methods with which I want to update things in the scope of these directives :

(may use different controllers later but with these same common methods)

```
myApp
.controller('SomeCommonController', function() {
    this.someMethod = function(data) { 
        // do something for updating scope variables 
    }
        ...
    return this;
})
.directive('myDir1', function() {
    return {
        controller: 'SomeCommonController',
        template : '<sub-dir ng-repeat="sth in aList" data="sth"></sub-dir>',
           ...
    }
})
.directive('myDir2', function() {
    return {
        controller: 'SomeCommonController',
        template : 'Something Different with calling <sub-dir data="otherData"></sub-dir>',
           ...
    }
})
.directive('subDir', function() {
    return {
        scope: { data : "=" }
        require: "^something",  // parent directive
        template: '<button ng-click="someMethod(data);"></button>'
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentDirectiveCtrl) {
            scope.someMethod = function(data) {
                parentDirectiveCtrl.someMethod(data);
            };
        },
           ...
    }
})
```

Is there a way to require only the controller of the caller directive? Or is there a better way to achieve the same behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so there is any way to find who is parent controller dynamically (I mean to say parent directive)

I'd suggest you to use require with array that means mention your require field in array, like here require would `require: ['?^^myDir1', '?^^myDire2']` then inside link function 4th parameter is of controller, if you `ctrl[0]` you could get controller of `myDir1` & if you do `ctrl[1]` then you will get controller of `myDir2`

> You must use `?^^` because there could be one of them would not
>   present in parent of directive

```
.directive('subDir', function() {
    return {
        scope: { data: "=" },
        require: ['?^^myDir1', '?^^myDir2'],  // parent directive
        template: '<button ng-click="someMethod(data);"></button>'
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentDirectiveCtrl) {
            if(parentDirectiveCtrl[0])
              console.log('Parent controller is myDir1')
            if(parentDirectiveCtrl[1])
              console.log('Parent controller is myDir2')
            //whenever you want to call method of parent directive 
            //then you should use either parentDirectiveCtrl[0] for myDir1
            //or parentDirectiveCtrl[1] for myDir2
            scope.someMethod = function(data) {
                parentDirectiveCtrl[0].someMethod(data);
            };
        },
           ...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`require` is there to access another directive's controller (and thus "API"), and so you need to specify explicitly which directive you want. Otherwise, how would Angular know - there could be N number of "parent" directives. For example:

```
<parent ng-switch="abc" foo="123" bar>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

Which of the directives `parent`, `ngSwitch`, `foo`, `bar` you would expect Angular to return?

It is a very rare case that you need to determine dynamically what the hosting directive is, even if you know that the controllers have the same "API". And, clearly, `require` was not designed for that.

If you have a well-defined set of potential parent directives, then I second @pankajparkar's approach with *optionally* `require`-ing them all:

```
require: ["?^^parent1", "?^^parent2", ],
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){
   var parentCtrl = ctrls[0] || ctrls[1]; // etc...
}
```

If not, you *could* get the parent, but you would have to do some manual work. Suppose you ***know*** that a parent will always be the immediate containing element and the element tag (rather than an attribute) is the directive. Then, you could get that directive's controller like so:

```
link: function(scope, element){
   var parentCtrlName = element.parent().prop("tagName").toLowerCase();
   var parentCtrl = element.parent().controller(parentCtrlName);

   if (parentCtrl){
     //
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how about having a container parent directive that can contain either dir1 or dir2; then dir1, dir2 and subDir will communicate through the container directive, granted when you use the set of directives you need to wrap them in the container directive but it buys you flexibility, it will let you add dir3 without modifying the structure

```
myApp
.controller('SomeCommonController', function() {
    this.someMethod = function(data) { 
        // do something for updating scope variables 
    }
    ...
    return this;
})
.directive('container', function() {
    return {
        controller: 'SomeCommonController',
        template : '<container></container>',
           ...
    }
})
.directive('myDir1', function() {
    return {
        require: '^container',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentDirectiveCtrl) {
            scope.someMethod = function(data) {
                parentDirectiveCtrl.someMethod(data);
            };
        },
        template : '<sub-dir ng-repeat="sth in aList" data="sth"></sub-dir>',
           ...
    }
})
.directive('myDir2', function() {
    return {
        ink: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentDirectiveCtrl) {
            scope.someMethod = function(data) {
                parentDirectiveCtrl.someMethod(data);
            };
        },
        template : 'Something Different with calling <sub-dir data="otherData"></sub-dir>',
           ...
    }
})
.directive('subDir', function() {
    return {
        scope: { data : "=" }
        require: '^^container',  // parent directive
        template: '<button ng-click="someMethod(data);"></button>'
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentDirectiveCtrl) {
            scope.someMethod = function(data) {
                parentDirectiveCtrl.someMethod(data);
            };
        },
           ...
    }
})
```